# Unable to hide CONNECT requests in Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

I'm using Fiddler v4.6.20171.26113 on Windows 8.1. I have enabled the **Hide CONNECTs** option under the **Rules** menu and even tried put this script in the custom rules file:

```
if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT"))
{
    oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
}
```

However the CONNECT requests are still shown even when their flag `UI-HIDE: true` is set.

```
SESSION STATE: Done.
Response Entity Size: 0 bytes.

== FLAGS ==================
BitFlags: [ResponseGeneratedByFiddler, IsDecryptingTunnel, ProtocolViolationInRequest, RequestBodyDropped] 0x10a100
HTTPS-CLIENT-SESSIONID: empty
HTTPS-CLIENT-SNIHOSTNAME: mtalk.google.com
LOG-DROP-REQUEST-BODY: yes
LOG-DROP-RESPONSE-BODY: yes
UI-BACKCOLOR: LightYellow
UI-HIDE: true
X-CLIENTIP: ::ffff:***.***.**.**
X-CLIENTPORT: 5033
X-EGRESSPORT: 55428
X-HOSTIP: **.***.***.***
X-HTTPPROTOCOL-VIOLATION: [ProtocolViolation] HTTP/1.1 Request was missing the required HOST header.
X-ORIGINAL-HOST: 
X-REQUESTBODYFINALLENGTH: 1,384
X-RESPONSEBODYTRANSFERLENGTH: 0

== TIMING INFO ============
ClientConnected:    07:05:03.136
ClientBeginRequest: 07:05:03.339
GotRequestHeaders:  07:05:03.339
ClientDoneRequest:  07:05:03.339
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 61ms
HTTPS Handshake:    215ms
ServerConnected:    07:05:03.777
FiddlerBeginRequest:    07:05:03.777
ServerGotRequest:   07:05:03.777
ServerBeginResponse:    00:00:00.000
GotResponseHeaders: 00:00:00.000
ServerDoneResponse: 00:00:00.000
ClientBeginResponse:    07:05:03.777
ClientDoneResponse: 07:05:03.777

    Overall Elapsed:    0:00:00.437

The response was buffered before delivery to the client.

== WININET CACHE INFO ============
This URL is not present in the WinINET cache. [Code: 2]
* Note: Data above shows WinINET's current cache state, not the state at the time of the request.
* Note: Data above shows WinINET's Medium Integrity (non-Protected Mode) cache only.
```

So what should I do now?

Comment: Right-click one of the affected `Sessions` and choose `Properties`. Update your question with the content of the window that appears.

Comment: @EricLaw I've updated the question as you requested. Please do check.